# Why is $\theta(n*log_{2}(n))+\theta(k*log_{2}(n)$ equal to $\theta(n*Log_{2}(n))$?

Tags: polynomials, education

I've come across a problem.

If I have a row like this `P = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`
and `|P| = K`.

How can `merge sort` & `search` be equal to the same as `merge sort`?

Comment: We know that merge sort is $O(nlogn)$ then search is $O(n)$, so merge sort larger (by asymptotic) than search.

Comment: So it equals to the worst asymptotic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theta notation is concerned witht he behavior for large $n$.  In this case,
for large $n$, the ratio of 
$$
\frac{n \log_2n}{n \log_2n+ k \log_2 n} 
$$
approaches $1$ as $n \to \infty$. (Note that hohwever large $k$ is, eventually $n$ becomes a lot larger than $k$.)

So the expression in the denominator is not at all distinguished from the expression in the numerator under the "fuzzy asymptotic filtering" meant by $\theta(f(n))$.

Comment: So in the case of a merge and search of a konstant, `k`. The result set will always return the same, no matter the `k`? The only variable will be the length of the row that is being sorted and searched?